# Stopping a Thread Gracefully

Tags: python, python-multithreading

I was doing some reading([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18018033/how-to-stop-a-looping-thread-in-python),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18485098/python-threading-with-event-object),[3](https://christopherdavis.me/blog/threading-basics.html)) because I wanted to learn how to stop a thread properly.

I came up with a trivial example:

```
import time
import threading


def counting_numbers(stopper):
    for num in range(1,20):
        if not stopper.is_set():
            print(num)
            stopper.wait(2)


stop = threading.Event()
write = threading.Thread(target=counting_numbers, args=(stop,))
write.start()
time.sleep(5)
stop.set()
```

Suppose if this was a GUI application and I had a cancel button, would the `stop.set()` go inside the cancel button handler allowing the user to hit cancel and stop the count?

Comment: Did you try it?  did it work?

Comment: It did work, BUT just because it worked doesn't mean it's the proper practice or even the correct way of doing things

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any way to kill a Thread in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323972/is-there-any-way-to-kill-a-thread-in-python) Also see [How to stop a looping thread in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18018033/3904031)