# Multithreading: How to stop/edit individual threads?

Tags: python, multithreading

I am trying to create a method that will create threads and send them into a thread pool. How do I stop individual threads after creating them?
edit: This is being used for webscraping and will need to be ran in the background for days, it will be a dynamic number of processes and a number of other tasks(I only added 1 for reference. I also do not want the process to end upon completion (will loop the task) only to end upon user request

```
def Target(web,delay):
    log = ("starting")
    # gives headless option to chromedriver
    op = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    op.add_argument('headless')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=op)
    # launches driver with desired webpage
    driver.get(web)
    log = ("getting webpage")
    while [False != True]:
       try:
        #test to check if on correct page
            #looking for matching key
           log = ("checking stock")
           elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="viewport"]/div[5]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/button')
           if elem.is_displayed():
               log = ("instock")
               title= driver.title
               url= driver.current_url
               return (title, url)
       except NoSuchElementException:
           print("product is not in stock.... trying again")
           #retry delay
           time.sleep(float(delay))
           driver.get(web)

def multimethodv2(MethodToRun, url, delay,id):
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        pool = ThreadPoolExecutor()
        pool.submit(Target,url,delay)
```

Comment: `if __name__ == "__main__"` inside a function is not very idiomatic

Comment: If you are only running one task, there is no point here to using a thread pool. If you are running multiple tasks, then see [Python selenium multiprocessing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53475578/python-selenium-multiprocessing) for an idea on how to initialize the threads so that you are not re-creating the driver over and over again. In particular, see [my refinement to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53475578/python-selenium-multiprocessing/64513719#64513719), which modifies the accepted answer to ensure that the driver processes are terminated when you are done.

Comment: Right now, you have no call to `driver.quit()` at all, and that is not a great thing.

Comment: This is being used for webscraping and will need to be ran in the background for days, it will be a dynamic number of processes and a number of other tasks(I only added 1 for reference)

Answer (score 0):

I always add a variable called `running` and implement it as follows:

```
from threading import Thread

def do_stuff():
    while running:
        ...
        if running:
            ...
        else:
            break

        # let's say one thread found a solution:
        running = False

threads = 4
running = True

for i in range(threads):
    t = Thread(target=do_stuff, daemon=True)
    t.start()
```

All threads will check for the `running` variable and if one thread yound a solution or the program shall be stopped, this is set to `False` and the threads exit their loops. Works great in most cases.

If this is not suitable for you, you should checkout [threading events](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#event-objects)

See stackoverflow question for explanation: [Python Threading with Event object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18485098/python-threading-with-event-object)

Comment: The issue is I need to create these tasks dynamically which is why I am leaning towards using a thread pool.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot, nor would you want to, stop individual threads in a thread pool. They will all terminate when a `shutdown` of the pool is performed, in one of two ways:

When using ThreadPoolExecutor, you call the `shutdown` method *or* you use a context manager: `with ThreadPoolExecutor() as pool:`

```
def multimethodv2(MethodToRun, url, delay,id):
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=1) as pool:
        future = pool.submit(Target,url,delay)
        result = future.result() # wait for submitted task to end first before terminating block
```

Or:

```
pool = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=1)
future = pool.submit(Target,url,delay)
result = future.result() # wait for submitted task to end first before terminating pool
pool.shutdown()
```

Or:

```
pool = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=1)
future = pool.submit(Target,url,delay)
pool.shutdown(wait=False) # return immediately
result = future.result() # if this is last completed future, the pool will now shutdown
```

**But you should still call arrange to call `driver.quit()` or else a driver process will be left around:**

```
import threading
import gc
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from selenium import webdriver
# etc.


threadLocal = threading.local()


class Driver:
    def __init__(self):
        log = ("starting")
        # gives headless option to chromedriver
        op = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        op.add_argument('headless')
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=op)

    def __del__(self):
        self.driver.quit() # clean up driver when we are cleaned up
        #print('The driver has been "quitted".')

        
def create_driver():
    the_driver = getattr(threadLocal, 'the_driver', None)
    if the_driver is None:
        the_driver = Driver()
        setattr(threadLocal, 'the_driver', the_driver)
    return the_driver.driver



def Target(web,delay):
    driver = create_driver()
    # launches driver with desired webpage
    driver.get(web)
    log = ("getting webpage")
    while [False != True]:
       try:
        #test to check if on correct page
            #looking for matching key
           log = ("checking stock")
           elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="viewport"]/div[5]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/button')
           if elem.is_displayed():
               log = ("instock")
               title= driver.title
               url= driver.current_url
               return (title, url)
       except NoSuchElementException:
           print("product is not in stock.... trying again")
           #retry delay
           time.sleep(float(delay))
           driver.get(web)


# pool is now passed a an argument:
def multimethodv2(pool, MethodToRun, url, delay,id):
    future = pool.submit(Target,url,delay)
    return_value = future.result()

        
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    N_THREADS = 1 # Put in a more realistic value when you have a more realistic example
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=1) as pool:
        multimethodv2(pool, MethodToRun, url, delay, id)
    threadLocal = None # clean up drivers
    gc.collect()
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply, the main hurtle is that I am creating these treads/futures dynamically and want the user to be able to terminate the thread upon request.

Comment: @MichalPisarek So, what is the real issue? The threads exist to process new *tasks* as they are submitted with either the `submit` or `map` method of your `ThreadPoolExecutor` instance. Also see my comment to your question concerning efficiently reusing a Chrome driver in these threads. You can avoid creating and quitting the driver for each new URL and do it once per worker thread in your pool.

Comment: I've updated the answer with code to show how you might one Chrome driver per worker thread.