# Why th1 is not killed in the following python code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

```
from threading import Thread
import threading
import random
import time


class MyThread(Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.count = 0

    def run(self):
        time.sleep(1)
        this_name = threading.current_thread().getName()
        print("%s has begin to eat" % this_name)
        while True:
            self.count += 1

            print("%s has eaten %s hambergurs" % (this_name, self.count))
            time.sleep(random.random()*4)


th1 = MyThread()
th2 = MyThread()

th1.start()
th2.start()


del th1
print("th1 is deleted")
print(th1)
```

The output of the code is the following:

*th1 is deleted

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "D:/Data/data_file/pycharm_project/test/test.py", line 33, in 

print(th1)

NameError: **name 'th1' is not defined**

Thread-1 has begin to eatThread-2 has begin to eat

Thread-2 has eaten 1 hambergurs

Thread-1 has eaten 1 hambergurs

Thread-2 has eaten 2 hambergurs

Thread-1 has eaten 2 hambergurs

Thread-1 has eaten 3 hambergurs

Thread-2 has eaten 3 hambergurs*

So after the following code

```
del th1
```

th1 is deleted
but *Thread-1* is still running

```
del th1
```

why the above code does not kill *Thread-1*?

Comment: You deleted the variable `th1`, but the object it referred to still exists.

Comment: Just FYI... killing threads is not generally a good practice. In general, it is often preferable to set an *"event"* that threads check and then exit gracefully if it is set.

Comment: See [Is there any way to kill a Thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/323972/3890632)

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18485098/python-threading-with-event-object

Answer (score 0):

if you insist on using del command you can you the following code:

```
class MyThread(Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.count = 0
        self.__kill = False

    def run(self):
        time.sleep(1)
        this_name = self.name
        print("%s has begin to eat" % this_name)
        while not self.__kill:
            self.count += 1

            print("%s has eaten %s hambergurs" % (this_name, self.count))
            time.sleep(random.random()*4)

    def kill(self):
        self.__kill = True

    def __del__(self):
        self.__kill = True
```

and now you can use `th1.kill()` and `del th1`

p.s use `self.name` instead of `threading.current_thread().getName()`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).